# how do I pass data upwards in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have an app with some path `app -> taskbar -> button -> modal -> textfield`. I want the textfield to be some setting a user inputs and is used elsewhere in the app, maybe `app -> differentButton -> differentModal` displays this user setting for example

I'm brand new to react, but it seems data can only go downwards through props, right? Is it expected that I store this state externally in a db? I don't *mind* doing that, but it seems like there should be an easy way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: You can store state in a parent component (or redux) and pass this down, along with callback functions to change the state. You should read the React docs/tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the state in the parent component and pass not only the *value*, but also the *function that modifies the value* to the child.  Eg:

```
const App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            name: 'Dave'
        };
    },
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent name={this.state.name} changeName={this.onChangeName} />
            </div>
        )
    },
    onChangeName (name) {
         this.setState({ name });
    }
});

const MyComponent = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
         name: React.PropTypes.string,
         changeName: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.changeName} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: well worded, in retrospect it's kind of similar to how nodejs works. i guess the boilerplate clouded my vision

Comment: Yeah, I was going to update with notes about flux/redux etc... but the other guy beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way would be to pass a callback function from a component which is higher up in the view hierarchy through props.

That higher ordered component would encapsulate the state that you wish to modify, triggering a re-render of the sub-tree.

In your case, it looks like you would have to use `App` as the shared parent component for sharing state. So in `App`, you'd probably have a function such as:

```
  handleTextInput: function(text) {
    // handle the text input here (set some state, make an ajax call, etc)
  },
```

And `App`'s `render` function might look like this:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
        <TaskBar onTextSubmit={this.handleTextInput} />
    );
  }
```

In your `TaskBar` component, you'd pass the callback down to `Button`, and so on.

Finally, in your `modal` component, you'd have a render function like:

```
 render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.onTextSubmit}>
       ...
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Of course, this is can quickly get quite clumsy if you have a deeply nested hierarchy, so a better approach would be to use a library for state management such as [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux).